# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el primer día del mes?

Tags: java

Quisiera saber cómo obtener el primer día del mes para verificar si dicho día cae Sábado o Domingo.
Con la clase Calendar he podido obtener la cantidad de semanas que hay en un mes, los días de la semana, etc, pero aun no logro obtener ese primer día del mes, estuve revisando la API y no veo que tenga esta función.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");//Formato que voy a utilizar Año/Mes/Dia
               
//Creo una variable y le envio la fecha de miJDateChooser como un String debido al formato
                String fechaFormato = sdf.format(Fecha.getDate());
                Date FormatoFecha;
try {

FormatoFecha = sdf.parse(fechaFormato);//Paso la fecha String como un Date
Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();//Creo la clase Calendar
calendario.setTime(FormatoFecha);//Enviola fecha del JDateChooser al Calendar
System.out.println("Fecha enviada del JDateChooser"+fechaFormato);//Probando que la Fecha se envíe bien

//Visualizar algunos datos de la clase Calendar                 
System.out.println("Dia de la semana en el mes: "+calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH));
System.out.println("Dia de la semana: "+calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
System.out.println("Dia del mes: "+calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                } catch (ParseException e1) 

                {

                getToolkit().beep();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo cargar la fecha", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


               }
```

Estos son ejemplos sencillos que he podido hacer, pero aun no doy con la solución a mi problema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te recomiendo no usar en lo posible las clases Calendar y java.util.Date. Son clases antiguas con muchos métodos *deprecated* (desaconsejados).

Desde Java 8 tienes disponible el API [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html):

```
LocalDate d= LocalDate.parse("2020-08-12").withDayOfMonth(1);
DayOfWeek dw=d.getDayOfWeek();
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, me sirvió tu comentario.
Comenzaré a aprender sobre la API Java.Time.

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener el primer día del mes, simplemente obtenga una Date y establezca el día actual al día 1 del mes. Borrar hora, minuto, segundo y milisegundos si lo necesita.

```
private static Date firstDayOfMonth(Date date) {
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.setTime(date);
   calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
   return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Muy bien, gracias amigo!!!

Comment: de nada espero que te haya ayudado